# ObservableCollection as base Class c#

Tags: c#, winforms, observablecollection

I have a class that is derived from ObservableCollection as listed below

```
public class Accounts : ObservableCollection<Account>
{
 public Accounts(){}
 // some code
 // mode plus plus code
}
```

at other place i have

```
Accounts.CollectionChanged += Accounts_CollectionChanged;
```

Now whenever i change/update or add any thing in Account , the below event fires and things are fine so far.

```
void Accounts_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
 switch (e.Action)
 {
   case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
    MessageBox.Show("Add");
    break;
   case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
    MessageBox.Show("Remove");
    break;
   case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
    MessageBox.Show("Replace");
    break;
   case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
    MessageBox.Show("Reset");
    break;
 }
}
```

However my problem (its painful) is the First event it gives me is 'Reset' always, no matter what i do (update any value in account or add another account). Then if there are 2 items in collection, 'Add' event will fire two times but Replace event DOESN'T Fire.

Second problem i am having is (kind of first problem) if i add any thing to the collection and if there are 4 items already in the collection it generates 'Add' event 5 times (first 4 times for existed items and 5th one for new item) and i am not sure what am if doing wrong or i don't know how to fix it. Any idea what needs to be done to handle this?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: It would help if you would show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. It's also not clear why you're deriving from `ObservableCollection<T>` - is that relevant to your problem? (That should be easy to find out once you've got a short but complete program...)

Comment: You might consider deriving from a `BindingList<T>` instead - it's more natural to WinForms than `ObservableCollection<T>`

Comment: @JonSkeet Reason for ObservableCollection is i want to know if any thing in Account has been Updated, Removed or Added. i am going to try to put a demo ..

Comment: I didn't ask why you're using `ObservableCollection<T>`. I asked why you were deriving from it. There's nothing in your question which indicates that you need to, nor that it's related to the problem. If it *is* related to the problem, then I suspect there are issues in the code that you've missed out.

Comment: @IvanStoev i already tried that, i am having same problem with Bindinglist also. Same problem i mean when i add a new item it fires Reset first then fires the add event per existing items. However, itemsChange for binding list is working fine

Comment: @JonSkeet i afraid i don't have another answer except that i only need to know that if item has been added, removed or updated... Sorry if i am wrong ..

Comment: In my experience it does not fire unnecessary Reset events. Jon is right, you need to post some code so we can see what the problem is. Most probably the way you use it.

Comment: Put it this way - why do you feel you need to create a class deriving from `ObservableCollection<Account>` rather than just using `ObservableCollection<Account>` directly in your code?

Comment: @JonSkeet because there are multiple classes that belong to my model i.e. Account, AccountHistory, and few more. I have 'ModelController' class that keeps eye on them.  So instead of using directly i thought i will make each class an observable and when ever any of them changes i will get the required info, that's why i derived it from ObservableCollection. I am going to try to put a demo so that makes thing a bit better

Comment: Sounds like you could easily have an `ObservableCollection<T>` for each of those. You haven't explained how you're *speciailzing* `ObservableCollection<T>` in any of those cases. Maybe you are, but just haven't explained why. But anyway, let's see the demo and try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Based on your problem description, it seems you have code _somewhere_ that is "updating" the list by calling `Clear()` and then re-adding all of the elements it wants. But without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it is impossible to say exactly how or why this is happening, never mind to suggest a fix. If some other code out of your control is doing this, then you'll just have to live with it. If the code is under your control, then provide a good code example so we can help.

Comment: ObservableCollection seems to have nothing to do with your problem. That's the PropertyGrid re-construct a new object everytime u made any change in the property grid. Imagine new Accounts instance caused the Reset and then re-add each Account instance one by one.

Comment: Did any one have any chance to look at it? Sorry